# Connecting the plates of 2 capacitors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, charge, capacitance

2 Capacitors C$_A=2~\mu$F and C$_B=4~\mu$F are charged by $100$ V separately. Then they disconnected from source, and connect **OPPOSITE plates of each other** by a wire. (+ of A to - of B and vice versa). By Q=CV, charge initially stored is Q$_A=200~ \mu$C, Q$_B=400~\mu$C.

So when connect opposite plates, I thought the small charge neutralized by the big charge. Thus I concluded finally there's only $200\,\mu$C on B capacitor and none on A. But my answer sheet tells finally charges are Q$_A= 67\,\mu$C and Q$_B=133\,\mu$C.

Could anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here? couldn't find help anywhere else. Thanks.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in combining the charges to get a total of $200\,\mu$F, but wrong in how they are distributed.  Because the two capacitors are now, effectively, in parallel, the voltages must be equal, so the remaining $200\, \mu$F of total charge will be re-distributed until $$V_A = V_B.$$

You can do the algebra and arithmetic from this point.

Comment: I think I am missing something here. How are they 'effectively parallel'? My guess is that since their opposite plates are connected (+ of one to - of other) they are in series. But I've seen something online that says if the capacitors are uncharged, their side doesn't matter. But here, they are charged. What am I missing? Link:https://www.quora.com/When-the-opposite-plates-of-two-charged-capacitors-are-connected-then-in-such-case-we-add-the-net-capacitance-why

Comment: Regardless the charge on the plates, whichever sides are connected together must come to the same potential as each other. The other sides coneected together will come to the same  (but different from the other side) potential as each other. The two sides are different because of the differing charge (+ 200 versus -200 $\mu$F). The means each capacitor has the same voltage as the other, effectively parallel. Draw the picture. Any two devices connected in series are also effectively parallel, if they are the only things in the circuit.

Comment: @Bill_N It worked! Thank you very much for great and easy-to-understand explanation sir!